# Probability of drawing at least 2 blue balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 3 types of balls: Red, green and blue. Each of them has equal probability of being drawn. What is the probability of having at least two blue balls out of 5 balls. Can somebody correct me since this should not be right answer(answer is $P(A) = \frac{10}{21} \approx0.476$).

The total number of possible outcomes |$\Omega$| = $3^{5}$

Let **A** be event of drawing at least 2 blue balls, therefore $A^c$ - drawing 0 i or 1 blue ball

for 0 blue balls: $2^5$

for 1 blue ball: $5\choose1$$\times2^4$

$P(A^c) = \dfrac{2^5 + {5\choose1}\times2^4}{3^5} \approx 0.46$

$P(A) = 1 - 0.46 = 0.54$

Comment: You can consider using binomial probability for this question.

Comment: Anyway, I think your solution is correct. Your textbook may have an error.

Comment: Your problem seems strangely posed. Do you put the ball back when you draw it or not ? Equivalently, Do you have an infinite amount of balls in that bag, so the probability of drawing a blue ball stays the same ? Or is the probability of drawing a blue ball affected by drawing a blue ball, or by drawing other ball colors ?

Comment: Ye i know its weird, its like a shop sells three types of balls in a box of 5 (random balls with equal probability). What is the probability you bought a box with at least 2 blue balls?

Comment: I can't find any error in your approach. The answer key must be wrong.

Comment: what if it said for example at least 3 blue balls, would i just **5 choose 2** times **2^3** in the numerator?

Comment: The answer below shows where the supposed solution $10/21$ comes from -- namely the "equal probability" refers NOT to colors of individual balls, but rather to outcomes of the form $r$ red, $b$ blue, $g$ green with $r+b+g=5$. There are $21$ such distinguishable outcomes, of which $10$ have at least $2$ blues. It's a weird distribution and not at all implied by the phrasing of the problem above.

Answer (score 2):

The answer $\frac{10}{21}$ is obtained in assumption that all combinations of $x_1$ red balls, $x_2$ green balls and $x_3$ blue balls with $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$, $x_i\geq 0$, $i=1,2,3$ are equally probable. That is, we can get $5$ red balls, or $4$ red and $1$ blue, or $2$ red, $2$ blue and $1$ green and so on, and all these cases have the same probability.

This is the scheme where $5$ indistinguishable balls are placed into $3$ distinct boxes R,G,B. It is not clear why this scheme is used for the given answer and how it can follow from the phrase

> Each of them has equal probability of being drawn.

I think that this problem is poorly worded. And the solution of OP is right.

Newertheless, if we assume that we place $5$ indistinguishable balls into $3$ distinct boxes R,G,B, then total number of outcomes is 
$$
|\Omega|=\binom{5+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{7}{2}=21
$$ 
and a number of outcomes with at least two blue balls is 
$$
|A|=\binom{(5-2)+3-1}{3-1}\binom{5}{2}=10.
$$

Comment: But it would be a very weird distribution to have the distinguishable stars-and-bars outcomes equally likely -- that never happens in ordinary models of randomly placing objects in boxes. That's a serious conceptual error in the book from which this problem is drawn ... nice work finding it!